# Какой вариант верный?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"В мероприятии участвовало 102 тыс. человек" или "в мероприятии участвовали 102 тыс. человек"?

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта верны, но какой из них употребить, зависит от смысла. Эти 102 тысячи были единым целым? Например, участвовали в демонстрации, выражая общее мнение?  Тогда *102 тысячи человек участвовало в демонстрации.* Если эти 102 тысячи принимали участие в олимпиаде, то, конечно, эти участвующие  - не единое целое, тогда правильнее будет сказать *102 тысячи человек участвовали в олимпиаде*.